# Group files by name prefix and then archive (zip) each group with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following situation:

I have a large number of files in a directory named as thus:

'######_dynamicname_timestamp.xml'

I want to group the files by ###### then zip the grouped files into an archive named after ###### of the group. In this situation the filename and timestamp are not important, only the first six digits.
I am new to PowerSHell and am not familiar with the commands (cmdlets?) just yet. Looking for the answer at ss64 I came across group-object however I still can't get it right. So far this is as all I got:

```
ls D:\directory\ | select name | group-object name
```

Due to the timestamp and dynamic filename each file is in its own individual group. I need a way to group only by the first six digits then pass those groups to a zip or archive command. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This pipeline should give you the desired result / the idea how to do it

```
Get-ChildItem D:\directory | 
    Group-Object -Property { $_.Name.Substring(0, 6) } |
    % { Compress-Archive -Path $_.Group -DestinationPath "$($_.Name).zip" }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Of note: This requires Powershell 5+. I was using Powershell 2 so I was getting a >>> after running the command